Negative externality in consumption to a Cobb Douglas utility function
I am performing a brief analysis with a Computable General Equilibrium Model approach. I want to apply a negative externality in consumption to a Cobb Douglas utility function, any idea to do it and make ordinary demands somewhat elegant?
I have tried multiplying by a factor $e^{-\delta x_i}$ for each good. Any other possible suggestions?
